# Confusion in Uniform Electric Field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, coulombs-law

I understand Electric Fields and also its dependence on 1$/r^2$. Although this dependence does not works in Uniform Electric Field. How is the magnitude of Electric Field/Force same at every place.

Why does Uniform Electric Field not follow the Coulumb's Law?

I saw some questions on this. The answer basically says to think about plate as point charges But i dont understand how it would mean that electric field will have same magnitude at every place. Because this "many charges" theory says that the vertical componets of each point charges is taken as a uniform field which means at every place(1/r^2) the component will be different so it is not unifrom.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explanation for $E~$ not falling off at $1/r^2$ for infinite line and sheet charges?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32948/explanation-for-e-not-falling-off-at-1-r2-for-infinite-line-and-sheet-char)

Comment: Closer duplicate: [Uniform Electric Field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173631/uniform-electric-field)

Comment: An electric field depends on $1/r^2$, where $r$ is the distance from a point charge. But what if you don't have just a point charge? What if you have many charges and you arrange them in a way that they all combined create a uniform electric field?

Comment: @Steeven..........yeah even i thought that this is correct. But i dont understand how it would mean that electric field will have same magnitude at every place. Because this "many charges" theory says that the vertical componets of each point charges is taken as a uniform field. Which means at every place the component will be different so it is not unifrom.

Comment: Do you understand there are dimensional assumptions/limitations for which the field is (approximately) uniform?

Comment: @BillN never read about it